# How to suppress "No matching autocommands"?

Tags: autocmd, functions, message

I have a log library that has a `autocmd log User` hook, to show saved log or set it to a dedicated scratch buffer or etc.

It works quite well, but there is slight nuisance. When inspection/debug done, I clear the hook by `au! log User`. But then `No matching autocommands: log User` will show at cmdline constantly. Since the `log#log` function invoke `doa log User`.

**Problem**:
Is there a way to suppress the `No matching autocommands: log User` message when `doa log User` but no `log User` autocmd being set.
Or is there a function to check existence of a specified autocmd, if no one, then do not `doa` (to avoid `No matching autocommands` noise).

**Failed attempts**:

- use `sil doa`, then hook that just echoes will never work. Unacceptable.

Comment: See `:h exists()`

Answer (score 1):

Thx to Matt's comment. Found the answer in `:h exists`.

the relevant part is.

```
    #event      autocommand defined for this event
    #event#pattern  autocommand defined for this event and
                    pattern (the pattern is taken
                    literally and compared to the
                    autocommand patterns character by
                    character)
    #group      autocommand group exists
    #group#event    autocommand defined for this group and
                    event.
    #group#event#pattern
                    autocommand defined for this group,
                    event and pattern.
    ##event     autocommand for this event is
                    supported.
```

thus answer for my case is

```
    if exists('#log#User')
        doa log User
    endif
```